# Incorrect characters while fetching data from MySQL 5.5.35 with NodeJS 14.5.0

Tags: mysql, node.js, character-encoding

I am trying to retrieve some data from a **MySQL database (version 5.5.35)** using the `mysql` npm module in **NodeJS (14.5.0**).

**1.) Here are the database's character set variables:**

[image: character_set variables]

**2.) Server's encoding:**

[image]

**3.) Here are the settings of the table I am fetching data from:**

[image]

**4.) Here is how I am initiating the connection:**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const dbConfig = require('../../config/database.json');

dbConfig.connectionLimit = 10;
dbConfig.charset = 'utf8' // tried latin1, latin2 and utf8mb4

console.log(dbConfig);

const connection = mysql.createPool(dbConfig);
 
module.exports = connection;
```

**5.) Here's the result wihtout any conversion:**

[image]

That field's value should be `Cieśliński`.

That field's value right now is `Cieœliñski`.

**6.) Here's the result when I set `dbConfig.charset` to different encodings:**

- latin1: `Cie�li�ski`.
- latin1, then conversion from latin1 to utf8 with `Iconv`: `Cieï¿½liï¿½ski`.
- utf8: Cieœliñski
- utf8, then conversion from latin1 to utf8 with `Iconv`: `CieÅ“liÃ±ski`.

Proper value should be: `Cieśliński`.

**Question: How should I set up my NodeJS server to properly fetch the proper value of the field? (`Cieśliński`)**

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/10310278 I hopes that this can help you

Comment: @cvekaso Thank you for this comment. I will check it out.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` so we can see what is _really_ on disk.

Comment: @RickJames provided it in a comment under your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hex `9CF1`:

```
latin1:  œñ
cp1250:  śń
```

That is, somewhere in the specification, you are using latin1 when you should be specifying cp1250.

UTF-8 (utf8, utf8mb4) is not involved.

After you have provided `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...`, I can tell you whether it is messed up in the table or not.

Comment: Sorry for responding late, here is the result:
`Cieœliñski`, `4369659C6C69F1736B69`

Comment: Note the `9C` and `F1` in that hex string.

Comment: This would mean that it's a Windows 1250 encoding. But whenever I convert `œñ` from latin1 to Windows 1250 with `Iconv` I get gibberish. EDIT: I actually get an ELISEQ error from what I remember. Can't check it right now.

Comment: Don't use any conversion routine; just tell MySQL the correct encoding.

Comment: Interestingly - when I connected to the database using `cp1250` without any conversion routine and I turn the text into HEX inside of my application (instead of doing it directly in MySQL) I get this HEX: `4369653f6c693f736b69`. This is the field's value without any conversion routine: `Cie?li?ski`.

Comment: @Pe-Ter - That's because the configuration is misrepresenting what the encoding for displaying.  Check `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and the connection parameters for node.js and the them `<meta>` if relevant.  I _think_ any of those could cause the "question marks".